# In TileMill/CartoCSS how do show several markers for the same point?

Tags: tilemill, cartocss

I'm creating a custom map using TileMill to show local walks.

I want to show Points Of Interest along the path.
I've exported the points from Google Maps using KML and I want to show an icon on a background for each.

I have a pin icon and the icon for each location but I can't work out how to display one on top of the other.

I've looked into using a point and a marker but point doesn't allow color styling and I would like to color the background pin as well as the icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** Got a winner! You can use [instances](https://github.com/mapbox/carto#attachments-and-instances) to do this. Like attachments, naming is arbitrary but order is not

```
#layer {
  background/marker-allow-overlap: true;
  background/marker-file: url('path/to/background.svg');
  background/marker-fill: #111;
  background/marker-line-color: #111;
  background/marker-line-width: 9;
  background/marker-width: 26;
  marker-allow-overlap: true;
  marker-file: url('path/to/foreground.svg');
  marker-fill: #fff;
  marker-width: 18;
}
```

---

My previous "answer" was not great, but some may still find it applicable:

The closest thing I could think of to a solution (not for me since I'm using CartoDB and not MapBox) is to use font icons, which [MapBox Studio now supports](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/mapbox-studio-custom-fonts/). You could bring in something like [IcoMoon](https://icomoon.io/) or [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) if you have relatively standard icons, in which case you could use a marker as your background and the font icon as your foreground, both of which could be styled.

I couldn't tell from your "can't work out how to display one on top of the other" sentence if you already tried stacking markers, but if not then try something like this:

```
#layer {
  ::background {
    marker-width: 26;
    marker-fill: #111;
    marker-file: url('path/to/background.svg');
    marker-allow-overlap: true;
  }
  ::foreground {
    marker-width: 18;
    marker-fill: #fff;
    marker-file: url('path/to/foreground.svg');
    marker-allow-overlap: true;
  }
}
```

Great manual on CartoCSS [here](http://skorasaurus.github.io/carto-manual/). Hope this helps, keep us posted if you find something!

Comment: I'll give this a go and see what happens!